# jsf2 highlight components with FacesMessages (o:highlight)

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

i have some input components that should be validated only when a specific action is executed under all other circumstances they should accept every input.

This way i can't use a normal validator but have a commandButton that evaluates the data in it's action Method and creates some FacesMessages related to specific clientIds if something is missing.

Now i normaly use the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [o:highlight](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) component to point to fields that require further action but in this case the input-components are valid and thus the highlight component does not take them into account.

Now i wonder if it would be possible to have this behavior depended on the List of Ids with Messages.

Something like this:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getClientIdsWithMessages(); it.hasNext();) {
        String clientId = it.next();
        List<FacesMessage> messageList = FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getMessageList(clientId);
        if (messageList != null) {
            for (FacesMessage msg : messageList) {
                ... // build json with clientIds (maybe check for UIInput
            }
        }
}
```

If needed this way one could possibly introduce new Style classes for info, warn and error messages. Maybe it's even a bit faster cause not the whole component tree has to be visited, but that s just a guess.

So what s your opinion? This is a rather hard change on the current behavior so i m not sure if this guess will make it into omnifaces or must be implemented individualy.

Answer (score 0):

> *Now i wonder if it would be possible to have this behavior depended on the List of Ids with Messages.*

From the javadoc of the very same method as you [linked](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/1.8.1/src/org/omnifaces/component/script/Highlight.java#L115) there:

> Note that the [FacesContext#getClientIdsWithMessages()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getClientIdsWithMessages%28%29) could also be consulted, but it does not indicate whether the components associated with those client IDs are actually [UIInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components which are not [UIInput#isValid()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29).

So, you would for every single client ID still need to use `UIViewRoot#findComponent()` in order to find the component, figure its type and verify the validity. This is much more expensive than a single tree visit.

If you really need to perform validation in action method, your best bet is to mark the context and inputs as invalid yourself.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.validationFailed();
((UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(clientId)).setValid(false);
```

Alternatively, to satisfy the concrete functional requirement,

> *i have some input components that should be validated only when a specific action is executed under all other circumstances they should accept every input.*

just use a normal validator wherein you check the invoked action:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("formId:buttonId")) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I.e. when `<h:form id="formId"><h:commandButton id="buttonId">` is invoked, then validation will be performed. That's always better than performing validation at the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, i'll have to use the first approach, because 2nd won't work, as i have to check some required fields and the problem with them is, that the surrounding component (a rich:tabPanel with switchType="ajax") will submit it's complete content (so the button i look for too) on changing the tab and i am not able to influence this in any way (at least not at the moment).
Anyway the idea of different styles for different FacesMessage.SEVERITY types is not interesting for you? I thought it could be useful to highlight components by Message not only when they are invalid.